# Windows 10 key re-assignment

Tags: function-keys

For a variety of reasons, I have an unusually complex email address which is tiresome to keep re-typing.  Is there any way I can re-program one of my little used Windows 10 keys, such as a function key, to hold this address?

Comment: Yes. Something like [autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Create text file "email.txt" and put your email into it.
Next create another text file and paste following code into it:

```
Option Explicit
Dim wshShell
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run ("cmd.exe /C clip < email.txt"), 0, true
```

Rename this file "email.vbs". This vbscript file (email.vbs) won't allow to assign shortcut key, so create a shortcut of the "email.vbs" and then you can assign shortcut key to it.

Every time shortcut key is pressed, content from email.txt (your email address) is being copied to clipboard and you can paste it easily.

Comment: Plz note that this answer does not involve third party programs like "autohotkey" and task could be accomplished with using existing tools/programs.